# Lightning Community Design Tokens Stopped Working in Winter 21

Tags: lightning-community, design-tokens, winter21

Have Lightning Community design token stopped working in Winter 21?

We have a defaultTokens bundle with the following code:

<aura:tokens extends="force:base">
<aura:token name="brandColor1" value="{!colorTextLink}"/>
</aura:tokens>

This is displaying the correct background color as entered into the Community Theme 'Link Color'

[image: Community Theme Colors Setting]

As per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard_communities.htm

However, we are now seeing that when we change the Link Color in the Community Theme, and publish the changes, the colours do not update.

The css renders as:

var(--c-brandColor1, rgb(255, 183, 93))

The default colour (rgb(255,183,93)) is the 'correct' new colour assigned to Link Color but the colour 'stored' in the -c-brandColor1 variable is still the old colour.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Yes we tried forceCommunity:base

Comment: I've modified the header to <aura:tokens extends="forceCommunity:base"> but this does not seem to work either - is that what you've found too Moggy?

Comment: I have this same issue.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Winter '21. Here is the [Known Issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=communities-tokens-that-reference-branding-overridable-tokens-are-not-getting-the-correct-value&Id=a1p4V000001JidX) link if you want to track the progress. In the meantime, as a workaround, you can update the components to reference colorTextLink directly instead of "brandColor1".

Comment: This is great thanks Anudeep, but it appears these direct tokens are only available for fill and color properties and not background

Comment: Thx Anudeep, but the known issue was created after this post.